# Validar DNI registrado en Jquery .net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webservice, linq

Estoy intentando validar que el DNI del cliente no se repita en un registro hecho en Jquery con Ajax y WebMethod. Quiero replicar esta condicion de linq en Jquery, como podría hacerlo?:

```
if (listaCliente.Any(x => x.numeroDoc.Trim() == txtNroDoc.Text.Trim()))
        {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "CodigoRepetido()", true);
        }
```

Ya tengo un listado con web method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<Cliente> ListarCliente()
    {
        List<Cliente> Lista = null;
        try
        {
            Lista = ClienteLN.getInstance().ListarCliente();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Lista = null;
        }
        return Lista;
    }
```

Comment: Me parece que sería demasiado costoso que devuelvas toda la lista de clientes por webservice y hagas la comparación por javascript, es mejor crear un web service que sea ValidarDNI, al cual le envías lo que ingresa el usuario, ejecutas en el servidor tu mismo código de linq y retornas true o false si está o no repetido.

Comment: Si lo resolví maso menos así, y el mensaje del DNI ya registrado lo puse dentro del ajax.